# Read an input key from user

Tags: c#, key

I want to read input from the user while my form is active.

For example if a form is active, when I press F1 I expect that a new form will appear.

How can I do that?

This is my main form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevComponents.DotNetBar;

namespace SchoolManagmentSystem.Forms
{
    public partial class AddStudent : Office2007Form
    {
        public AddStudent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void buttonX3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void AddStudent_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)
                MessageBox.Show("hi");
        }        
    }
}
```

In my design file I have a textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void AddStudent_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F1) 
    {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your constructor add the following:

```
public AddStudent()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown +=new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(AddStudent_KeyDown);
}
```

Comment: Studee It's really work thanx, but It does not work with a my form I guess that because the textbox so plz tell me how can fix it?

Comment: @BassamBadr Please post the code so I can understand what you mean.

Comment: @BassamBadr revised my answer, give that a try